# Can you search old ChatGPT conversation within the Web UI?

Tags: chatgpt, chat, search

Is there a way to search for data/information in my old ChatGPT conversation  within the web UI, all at once with a keyword etc. I understand that the current conversation can't look at data from the old ones. But is there a way I can search through the old conversation myself with keyword rather than having look through them one by one?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify the scope of the answer that you are looking for. Please be clear if you are looking for a built-in feature, if you are open to export the conversations, use the browser developer tools, userscripts, APIs or third party tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your ChatGPT settings and select "Data controls".
Then press the "Export" button after the "Export data" label.

Then you will receive a mail with a link to a zip file containing all your chats. Download it.

Within the downloaded zip file, open "chat.html" in web browser. Here you can search for any string in all chats.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MaDev its not directly in the Web UI but seems to be the best option available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chatgpt-conversation-hist/ppnfnillfndkellpbphafglnljdefjph

Does full search on all your conversations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Web UI. As mentioned above, you can export your data from settings, or use a browser extension like Searchable ChatGPT.

But the search feature is present in the official ChatGPT mobile apps for both iOS and Android.